# IntelliJ pre-commit.com integration

Tags: intellij-idea, githooks, pre-commit.com

I'm using [pre-commit hooks](https://pre-commit.com/) in my project.

When I'm doing my commits from the `command-line` everything is great and the hooks are working but when I try to commit from the IDE it failed with the message:

> 0 file committed, 2 files failed to commit: dummy commit `pre-commit` not found. Did you forget to activate your virtualenv?

My `virtualenv` is active:

[image: activate your virtualenv]

What am I missing?

##Edit 1

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

`grep ^INSTALL .git/hooks/pre-commit` -> `INSTALL_PYTHON=/home/lioriz/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin/python`

`which pre-commit` -> `/home/lioriz/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin/pre-commit`

`head -1 $(which pre-commit)` -> `#!/home/lioriz/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin/python`

`pre-commit --version` -> `pre-commit 2.17.0`

##Edit 2

**.pre-commit-config.yaml:**

```
# See https://pre-commit.com for more information
# See https://pre-commit.com/hooks.html for more hooks
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v3.2.0
    hooks:
    -   id: trailing-whitespace
    -   id: end-of-file-fixer
    -   id: check-yaml
    -   id: check-added-large-files
```

**.git/hooks/pre-commit:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# File generated by pre-commit: https://pre-commit.com
# ID: 138fd403232d2ddd5efb44317e38bf03

# start templated
INSTALL_PYTHON=/home/lioriz/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin/python
ARGS=(hook-impl --config=.pre-commit-config.yaml --hook-type=pre-commit)
# end templated

HERE="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
ARGS+=(--hook-dir "$HERE" -- "$@")

if [ -x "$INSTALL_PYTHON" ]; then
    exec "$INSTALL_PYTHON" -mpre_commit "${ARGS[@]}"
elif command -v pre-commit > /dev/null; then
    exec pre-commit "${ARGS[@]}"
else
    echo '`pre-commit` not found.  Did you forget to activate your virtualenv?' 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
```

`test -x /home/lioriz/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin/python; echo $?` -> `0`

##Edit 3

The IntelliJ runs on `Windows 11` with `WSL2`, and the `pre-commit` is installed in the `wsl2` - `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS`

Comment: try re running `pre-commit install`? it must have moved since last execution

Comment: @anthonysottile, I ran `pre-commit install` again, did not help. I looked at `pre-commit` location: `which pre-commit`->`/home/lioriz/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin` added it to `PATH` in `~/bashrc` and still had the same issue.

Comment: are you on a super old version of `pre-commit`?

Comment: @anthonysottile just added info, please see `#Edit 1`, Do you need more info?

Comment: does the contents of your `.git/hooks/pre-commit` look like this? https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/blob/v2.17.0/pre_commit/resources/hook-tmpl (or is it a python file (older)) -- and does `test -x /home/lioriz/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin/python; echo $?` give you `0`? the first branch should be taken -- otherwise intellij is doing something nefarious

Comment: @anthonysottile the content of `.git/hooks/pre-commit` is the same except for those lines: `# start templated
INSTALL_PYTHON=/home/lioriz/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin/python
ARGS=(hook-impl --config=.pre-commit-config.yaml --hook-type=pre-commit)`, 
           `test -x /home/lioriz/anaconda3/envs/py36/bin/python; echo $?` gives 0.

Comment: are you maybe running intellij from a snap?

Comment: @anthonysottile No snap, `Windows 11` with `WSL2`

Comment: oh yeah that's never going to work unless your intellij is also running inside wsl

Comment: Gotcha, Thanks! I will see what I can do about that.
I guess This is the answer to my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251925/discussion-between-lior-i-and-anthony-sottile).

Answer (score 1):

Look at this Thread https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-12988, check the last replay.

> I have set path to Git executable in my case \wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\usr\bin\git
> and pre-commit installed globally (not inside venv) just worked

[image: Git binary from the WSL]

I tried this on my ENV - windows 10 with IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.4 (Ultimate Edition) and WSL - and this working just fine.